# C# Multiplication Table

Tags: c#, loops, multiplication

So I'm attempting to print a multiplication table in C# however I can't quite figure out how to get what I need.

So far my program outputs the following:

1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9

However, I need it to output this:

0 1 2 3
1 1 2 3
2 2 4 6
3 3 6 9

I've tried a lot of different ways to get the second output however I can't quite figure it out. I'm not necessarily asking for an answer but if someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

This is the code I have as of now:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(i * j + "\t");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: The first line in the second output should be easy. Just print the number from 0 to n.

For the other lines, just print an extra number in before you print the multiplication table. You should know what to print, right?

Comment: Should you add the Homework tag to this question?

Comment: How is what you need a multiplication table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    Console.Write(i + "\t");
    for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
    {
        if (i>0) Console.Write(i * j + "\t");
        else Console.Write(j + "\t");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should skip both 0's.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
     {
          Console.Write((i == 0? j : (j == 0? i : i*j)) + "\t");
     }
     Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int tbl= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int j = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
     for (int j=1;j<=10; j++)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}={2}", i, j, (i * j));`enter code here`
     }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of this three solutions.

Solution 1 (without if else statement):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}\t", i);
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}\t", i * j);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Solution 2 (With if else statement):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}\t", i);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("{0}\t", i * j);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Solution 3 (With short-hand if else statement):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}\t", (i == 0) ? i : i * j);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
            {

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(j);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(j == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(i * j);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter A Number");
int j = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 10; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("{1} X {0} = {2}",i,j,i*j);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
/*
 * Write a console-based application that displays a multiplication table of the product of 
 * every integer from 1 through 10 multiplied by every integer from 1 through 10. Save the 
 * file as DisplayMultiplicationTable.cs.
 */

namespace MultiplicationTable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tMultiplication Table");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            const int END = 11;
            for(int x = 1; x < END; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 1; y < END; y++)
                {
                    int value = x * y;
                    Console.Write("{0} * {1} = {2}\t", y, x, value);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output

[Output of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tSgr.jpg)

I am attempting to complete the above code in a GUI.  So far I have come up with the following code; but the output is not like the above output.

My Code for the GUI is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DisplayMultiplicationTableGUI
{
   public partial class Form1:Form
   {
     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

    private void ShowTableButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        const int STOP = 11;

        for(a = 1; a < STOP; a++)
        {
            for(b = 1; b < STOP; b++)
            {
                int value = a * b; 
                multiplicationTableLabel.Text += String.Format("{0} * {1} = {2}     ", b, a, value);
            }
            multiplicationTableLabel.Text += "\n";
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please improve your answer by including at least a few more words to help explain it? (use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55929627/edit) button)

Comment: Please add some explications. What do you want to do, what is wrong etc.

Comment: I was providing answer to post.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    //int  num;
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       int num,num1;
       Console.WriteLine("enter a  any number num");
       num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       Console.WriteLine("enter any second number num1");
       num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       for(int i = num;i <= num1; i++)
       {
         for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
         {
           Console.Write(i *j+ "\t");
         }
       }
      Console.Write("\n"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: This code is 1 to n number output eg;1 to 5 table print enter number of table in range

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).